# Do we need Application Tier for Single Page Application

Tags: asp.net, n-tier-architecture

We are designing a new SPA application. Initially, we planned to have three tier application-

**Application Tier** (which will serve web pages and will behave as a proxy for all another data requests).

**Business Tier** (This will host WebAPIs for all business functionality).

**Database Tier** (To store the data).

Since this application will be an HTML5 application, can we bypass **Application Tier** for data request and directly call **Business Tier** from the browser?

1. One downside we can see is that it will result into CORS request
   and for some request Preflight will also come into the picture. That may slow it down a bit.
2. And if data is formed by combining data from external service hit, this logic will have to passed to browser.

Could you please suggest something on these lines?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tiers depend on what your architecture goals are, if it's performance than less tiers/physical separation will result in better performance. However there are other techniques you can use to mitigate performance such as caching.

In a typical scenario like this. It's better to separate the layers into separate physical layers such as an UI layer, API layer and data later. Also API is also a sort of UI, if u think carefully. Instead of delivering pages u are delivering data(json).

Keep in mind your business logic should be testable without involving any other layers.

I think the correct answer will always depend on your situation and architectural goals such as performance scalability, reliability, ease of change. etc etc.

But you can take this as a general guidance.